# The result repeats the message several times with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have this code:

```
<% @lookup_coins.each do |x| %>
    <% if @symbol == '' %>
        <%= 'Sorry, but you forgot to write something, LOL'%>
    <% elsif @symbol == x %>
        <%= x["symbol"]%> <br/> <%= x["name"]%>: <%= number_to_currency(x['quote']['USD']['price'].round(2) , :unit => "$ ") %> <br/> <%= x["cmc_rank"]%> <br/> 
    <% else 'Sorry, there was a mistake, try again'%>
<% end %>
```

The info looks like this:

```
[{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Bitcoin", "symbol"=>"BTC", "slug"=>"bitcoin", "num_market_pairs"=>9713, "date_added"=>"2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z", "tags"=>["mineable", "pow", "sha-256", "store-of-value", "state-channels", "coinbase-ventures-portfolio", "three-arrows-capital-portfolio", "polychain-capital-portfolio"], "max_supply"=>21000000, "circulating_supply"=>18633612, "total_supply"=>18633612, "platform"=>nil, "cmc_rank"=>1, "last_updated"=>"2021-02-20T07:45:02.000Z", "quote"=>{"USD"=>{"price"=>55541.51774356704, ...
```

I am not sure how to do it in the correct way

Comment: In Ruby `for` is not really used. This is typically expressed as `@lookup_coins['data'].each do |x|`. Additionally, if your first `if` branch tests for condition `X` then you just need an `else` to test for the opposite. `elsif !X` is pointless and error-prone.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, I saw some examples and is better, but I think that I am making something wrong, do yo mind help me one more time with the info I just edit?

Comment: Normally you use `<%- ... %>` for things you don't want to echo, but that just suppresses newlines and such in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're failing to match to the actual `symbol` value, but instead are expecting `@symbol` to perfectly match a Hash, which it won't.

Secondly, you're also printing that "forgot to write something" message each time through the loop which is wrong. You can get rid of the loop, just use `find` to locate the entry right away, and then as a bonus you can more easily detect a "missed" condition.

Just see if you can find a matching entry, otherwise display the message.

The fix looks like:

```
<%- if @symbol.blank? -%>
  Sorry, but you forgot to write something.
<%- else -%>
  <%- found = @lookup_coins.find { |c| c['symbol'] == @symbol } -%>
  <%- if (found) -%>
    <%= found["symbol"]%> <br/> <%= found["name"]%>:
    <%= number_to_currency(found['quote']['USD']['price'].round(2), :unit => "$ ") %>
    <br/>
     <%= found["cmc_rank"]%> <br/> 
  <%- else -%>
    Sorry, there was a mistake, try again
  <%- end -%>
<%- end -%>
```

Using `@symbol.blank?` here which is more forgiving than `== ''` as it will also reject a bunch of spaces and/or tabs.

Tip: Don't use `<%= '...' %>` Instead just put the text there as-is. The default is to echo it.

Comment: oh great tips! I imagine that I have to add the <% @lookup_coins.each do |x| %> at the on the top and <%end%> at the end, Because, if I dont do it, an error comes saying that the x is not defined, but when I add these, the message is shown several times, because in the info data I have several currencies.

Also, do you mind explain why do you writ it like <%- -%> instead of <% %>? I am so sorry, I am new with this RoR

Comment: If you do `<% ... %>` you'll see blank lines in your HTML output. `<%- ... -%>` suppresses those. Just makes your source smaller and easier to read.

Comment: That was a mistake. `x` should have been changed to `found`, which I just did in an edit.

Comment: that was great, just after the first 'found' I added an '=' because it sent me and error and now works perfectly. In case you want to added to your answer. Thak you so much for your help and tips

Comment: Good point, corrected. Don't forget to upvote anything that helps, and accept answers when they solve the problem. It marks it as a solution for others.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% if @symbol %>
<%@resultant_symbol = @lookup_coins['data'].select {|lookup_coin| lookup_coin["symbol"] == @symbol }%>
<%if @resultant_symbol.present?%>
   <% x = @resultant_symbol.first %>
   <%= x["symbol"]%> <br/> <%= x["name"]%>: <%= number_to_currency(x['quote']['USD']['price'].round(2) , :unit => "$ ") %> <br/> <%= x["cmc_rank"]%> <br/> 
<%else%>
   <%= @symbol = 'Sorry, there was a mistake, try again'%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I fixed it with the previous answer, but, do you mind explain me what are doing those .present? and .first

Comment: .present? will check whether the given element is not nil and not an empty string "" and not an empty array if in case its an array i.e., !variable.nil? && variable != "" && variable != []. and select method will return array of matching results, so I used .first to get the first element from the array.

Comment: If you think my answer is useful, you can give an upvote!!!, thank you.